# ios swift - UI Designer Adaptive iPhone Layout

Tags: ios, swift

I've disabled size classes in my project and have 3 view controllers.

By looking at the preview of each of the view controllers, I've noticed that the iPhone 6 which is the one I've been running the application on shows a layout completely different than how it looks when you run it on the actual phone.

I'm trying to build an application with size classes disabled that will have an adaptive layout between iPhones. I was under the impression that size classes was geared towards adaptivity between iPhone and iPad applications?

My app looks good on the iPhone 6 and terrible on the 6 plus. I would like the layout to be adaptive between both iPhones. Any advice?

Thank you

PS: Using autolayout

Comment: i think you may be checking something wrong as 6/6s has same screen resoultion/size so it will not have any design difference it may have some difference in 5s/6 plus if autolayout is not set properly

Comment: Also without design or basic example it is not possible to guide you much, so please provide some example screen and display the issues you are facing

Comment: I choose a view controller, split the screens, and select preview on the right side. Doesn't seem like much can go wrong. Are you saying that I don't need to enable size classes for the layout to look the same on 6/6s? I'm definitely utilizing auto layout correctly as it's pretty self explanatory but the layout looks way off on the 6s. Thanks for your help Pyro

Comment: yes if it's about 6 and 6s you don't need but if you are checking about 6 and 6 plus you will need some constraint setup,  For the size class part it's not compulsory to use size class you can give support with autolayout only also, Size class make that works easier than autolayout alone

Comment: My 6S comment up there was a typo. I'm sorry. I meant 6 plus. I'm utilizing size classes now and having some issues but I think I'll get it eventually. pretty annoying

Answer (score 0):

First of all enable Size classes. This is how you can vary the changes for 6 and 6+. If you want the similar layout on both the devices then use 600x600 size. If you want different layout in 6 and 6+ then you have to switch the size class and change the constraints accordingly. Refer this link for tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: 6 and 6+ express the same size classes in portrait

Comment: All iPhones have the same size classes, except the 6(s)+ which has Regular width on landscape (as opposed to Compact).